# Variadic function that passes non-PODs by reference and PODs by value

Tags: c++, function

This is not a question per se but more like a test to see if a feature in C++ is possible.

Can a function be created that:

- takes multiple arguments.
- parses each non-POD argument by value.
- parses each POD argument by reference (does not copy the argument).

I have attempted multiple solutions, but all failed in some case scenario or the other.

---

In the end, I want the framework for the solution to resemble the code below:

```
class Person {};

// Niladic: 0 Arguments
void array()

// Monoadic: 1 Arguments
void array(Person& element) {}
template <typename type> void array(type element) {}

// Variadic: Multiple Arguments --- How do we go about it?
void array(...) {}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // WORKS!
    array();
    array(Person());
    array(1);

    // ... --- How to go about this?
    array(1, Person(), Person());
    array(Person(), 2, Person());
    array(Person(), Person(), 3);

    array(1, 2, Person());
    array(Person(), 2, 3);

    array(Person(), Person(), Person());

    return 0;
}
```

---

The goal of this function is that it parses non-POD types without calling their constructor-destructor pairs again (does not 'copy' the object),

and that it can pass POD types as well.

*Yes, function templates are allowed*

Comment: I know questions like this are more of a homework assignment that wasn't asked for but I've reached the limit of my expertise for this problem and I'm just asking for help.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a way to do this with a function with a variable number of arguments (won't be possible) or would a function template also be acceptable (might be possible)? If a solution exists, it won't be straight forward. Side note: be aware that the notion of POD-types is being removed from C++, it has been superseded by the more refined concepts of trivially-copyable and standard-layout types…

Comment: Also: Why pass the *non*-POD types by value? Note that non-POD means it might not be copyable at all. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel. I should've explained earlier but the end goal is to prevent non-POD types from being copied (calling the constructor and destructor again) when they're parsed as arguments.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel. Yes, function templates are allowed, and non-straight forward methods are tolerable -- this being a project for learning.

Comment: “Passed”?  “Parsed”?  Do you mean you want to *accept* arguments by reference or not?  If so, how do you decide what argument *types* (reference or not) you’re accepting?  If it’s just “whatever you’re passed”, what are you going to *do* with these values (or references) of arbitrary type?